# Thanks for help vs. Thanks for helping me

Tags: expressions

Is the sentence 'Thanks for help' easily understood?

Should I use 'Thanks for helping me', or 'Thanks for help me'?

Comment: Your sentence is "easily understood", but as Paola implies, it's also easily recognised by competent speakers as "not correct English". For the others, "Thanks for helping me" is perfectly valid and common, but "Thanks for help me" is absolutely *terrible* English.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The only sentence which is correct is "*Thanks for **helping** me*", as the verb "to help" is preceded by a preposition and so needs to be a gerund.

If you prefer, you could use **help** as a noun; in this case, you should write *Thanks for **your help*** instead of your initial sentence.